# merging two array elements into one

Tags: c, arrays

After managing to correctly execute xor of chars between "$" and "*"  I need to perform "IF statement" to check if the xor indeed equals "64". I need to merge these two chars and somehow compare to the xor. The problem is i variables type. XOR (sumcheck) is in hex, the b (merging of 6 and 4) is in dec. Should i convert XOR to dec value, or convert 64(dec) to 64(hex) value?

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/D4qGDf)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

int i;
int xor = 0;
int b;
// $GPGLL,,,,,,V,N*64

char Received[18]= {'$','G','P','G','L','L',',',',',',',',',',',',','V',',','N','*','6','4'};
int loop;

// display array
//for(loop = 0; loop < 18; loop++)
//   printf("%c ", Received[loop]);

for(int i = 1; i<=14; i++)
    xor ^= Received[i];
    printf("%#02x  ", xor);
    printf("%d ", xor);

    b = ((Received[16]-'0') *10) + Received[17]-'0';
    printf("%d ", b);

if(xor == b){
    printf("WORKING!");
}
else{
    printf("not working");
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but this is wrong: `printf("%#02x  ", xor, "%d ", xor);` it should be `printf("%#02x  %d\n", xor, xor);`

Comment: I am missing the bracket around the for-loop

Comment: Please don't "correct" the code in your question as the answer bewlow doesn't make sense anymore. If you have another question, ask another question.

Comment: sorry for that stupid mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a `char` to `atoi` because it expects its input to be *pointer to char* (`char*`).

If you wants to use `atoi` you need to form the string yourself and pass it to `atoi` as below.

```
 char a[3] = {Received[16],Received[17]};
 b = atoi(a); //Base 10
```

Use `strol` for *base 16(HEX)* as below

```
 b = strtol(a,NULL,16);
```

If you don't want to use `atoi` or `strol` you can do as below.

```
 b = ((Received[16]-'0') *10) + (Received[17]-'0'); //Base 10
 b = ((Received[16]-'0') *16) + (Received[17]-'0'); //Base 16
```

Comment: atoi did work, however i wasn't able to display it. Second option is easier. Also i still have problems with the variables.. [DEMO](https://ideone.com/D4qGDf)  Am i right? i need to convert hex (xor sumcheck) value to dec?

Comment: @kabanos I'm not able to access your Link. What problems you are having with variables?

Comment: i've updated the question, your answer was very helpful. however now i need to perform if statement to check if xor (sumcheck) equals b (merging of 6 and 4). xor is in hex and b is in dec value. Can i convert 64(dec) to 64(hex)?

Comment: @kabanos use Base 16 conversion `b = ((Received[16]-'0') *16) + Received[17]-'0';`  Same I have already included in the answer.